# Using PySide / PyQt for mobile development

Tags: qt, mobile, cross-platform, pyside

I am currently looking at using PySide for mobile app development. I've done a few tutorials for creating desktop applications using Pyside and loving it. I understand PySide/PyQt is a port or mapping for Qt, and is usualy behind a little bit with Qt as developers of PySide/PyQt have to keep up with whatever happens in Qt.

I particularly want to develop for Android, BlackBerry and iOS. I also understand that Qt recently added support for Windows 8, as well as the more recent BlackBerry 10 OS.

**My question:** How well versed is PySide/PyQt in its current state with cross mobile application development.

Does it achieve mobile development by means of the WebKit component, allowing the use of everyday HTML, CSS and JavaScript?

Would it be a better option to consider PyQt for mobile app development, or PySide?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think its not realistic to think you can use PySide/PyQt and Python in order to make one application suitable for all those platforms.

First of all the platform you want to develop for should support your programming language (Python)  as well as the graphical framework (Qt) in order to make it work. This is mostly achieved by third party developers. If Python runs on your mobile operating system this does not say you can start developing and vice versa.

Mobile development is often done with [QML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QML) (Qt Modeling Language). This allows you to make really cool and fancy interfaces on many platforms. You can connect it to your own Python code to make a real working application.

At this moment Qt is working on support for mobile devices. Most mobile operating systems like iOS and Windows Phone are not supported yet for the combination Python/Qt and mostly the support for working projects is not really big in comparison to the preferred languages of the operating systems.

**Here is a list of mobile OS's which support the combination Python/Qt**

*Link to projects if there is a good link for a starting points is available*

**Android:** [PySide for Android](http://thp.io/2011/pyside-android/)

[or if you like to use "webviews" instead of PySide: SL4A](https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/)

**Blackberry 10:** [BB-py](http://blackberry.github.io/Community/Python.html)

**Meego:** [Python/Harmattan Project](http://wiki.meego.com/Python/Harmattan)

**SailFish OS:** [Harmattan apps (Meego) run without any problem](http://www.meegoexperts.com/2013/02/jolla-sailfishos-python-harmattan-apps-running-modification/)

For *your other questions* I have a shorter answer.
The webkit component is intended as a content viewer component. Its not a component for building  full HTML 5 apps.

The question which bindings for Qt are better is often asked. What you need to be aware of is that the old version of PyQt did almost the same as PySide. The difference was mainly in the license! However PyQt supports now Qt 5 while PySide doesn't, so make your own choice. I think you can make beautiful apps with both of them.

Comment: Nice answer. I was really under the impression that Qt has better support for cross mobile development, but it's nice to know that there's more coming soon.

Comment: @josef.van.niekerk Recent news: "With Qt you can develop truly cross-platform applications that will work on desktop, embedded and mobile platforms. Qt 5.2 introduces full support for Android and iOS platforms and thus enables the creation of cross-platform mobile apps that are packaged and deployed to both Google Play and App Store from one code base. Instead of writing two versions of the same code with two different technologies, you can write it once with Qt!" source: https://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2013/12/10/cross-platform-applications-in-ios-and-android-stores-with-qt/

Comment: @MountainX It's very good news that Qt 5 now supports Android and iOS. Unfortunately this question is also about Python and I haven't seen good mobile support for it in combination with Qt5. Please tell me if you know a Qt5+Python solution for mobile. Then I will update my answer.

Comment: Hmmm... so, nothing for iOS?

Comment: @supertwang I haven't seen running the combination Qt and Python on iOS. If you really want to use Python on iOS you should look into the Kivy project (http://kivy.org/).

Comment: @Ecno92 As of now, PyQt supports iOS http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqtdeploy/intro

Comment: @IronManMark20 I saw the PyQt deploy package too. It seems promising, but I can't find good examples of people actually using it yet.
Do you know if there are examples of projects that run successfully Python and Qt on Android and iOS using the PyQt deploy package?

Comment: I've really only found [this tutorial series](https://plashless.wordpress.com/2014/09/19/using-pyqtdeploy-on-macos-to-cross-compile-a-pyqt-app-for-ios-part-3/) by bootchk (Aka Lloyd konnekor). There isn't a ton out there. Most people I think don't want to buy a license.

Comment: I wish we could get a more recent answer to this question. A lot has happened since 2013.