# pyside2 for android development

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, pyside2

I would like to create app using pyside2/pyside6. I have gone through a couple of forums and found that android development can be done using qml.

So my question,
we have qml and python integration than indirect way we can create app using pyside2

https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/tutorials/qmlintegration/qmlintegration.html

they mentioned below page but curious, what we need for qml and android development

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/android-getting-started.html but not sure why we need this

one book claims it is possible
https://www.amazon.in/Python-GUI-Develop-Android-Applications-ebook/dp/B0891YRMJT

another question say it is not possible

[Using PySide / PyQt for mobile development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723258/using-pyside-pyqt-for-mobile-development)

any clarity using pyside2 for app development. or tutorial. I have search for a day but did not find any concrete example

Answer (score 0):

Basically it is possible by making a layout form gui which can fit in any resolution and size and use buildozer to compile it documentation:(https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest)

or as a better option, I will reffer to kivy...

for more info, checkout: [Using PySide / PyQt for mobile development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16723258/using-pyside-pyqt-for-mobile-development)

{[(Sorry for my bad english.)]}